# Adjective for people who think they should be given things

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I was wondering what adjective I could use for people with this character

> If something happens, then I should get something for free.

Examples:

- According to Estha, if they'd been born on the bus, they'd have got free bus rides for the rest of their lives.
  [*The God of Small Things*](https://www.bookbrowse.com/excerpts/index.cfm/book_number/414/page_number/2/the-god-of-small-things)
- They also believed that if they were killed on a zebra crossing, the government should pay for their funerals.
  [Same novel](https://www.bookbrowse.com/excerpts/index.cfm/book_number/414/page_number/2/the-god-of-small-things)

Can "Greedy" be used?

Comment: @Max I'm looking for people who have that character . Sorry qn was not specific

Comment: NOTE: Our **policy** is to provide links to **sources,** especially when they are still under copyright. as is the work of this author. Ms Roy's work is not in the public domain.

Answer (score 11):

One adjective that may work:

> **entitled**
>   *adjective*
>   believing oneself to be inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment.
>   *"kids who feel so entitled and think the world will revolve around them"*
>
> <sup>Source: Google define operation on *entitled*</sup>

This describes someone who thinks they deserve something. It can be money or other things.

If someone is always looking for a way to get something, we might say they are *opportunistic.*

> **opportunist**
>   *noun*
>   a person who takes advantage of opportunities as and when they arise, regardless of planning or principle.
>   *"most burglaries are committed by casual opportunists"*
>
> **opportunistic**
>   adjective
>   *"the calculating and opportunist politician"*

<sup>Source: Google define operation on *opportunist*</sup>

Comment: The problem with _entitled_ is that no dictionary I can find defines it as a pejorative. This use is idiomatic and requires context. _Greedy_ in contrast is definitive.

Comment: @P.E.D People who *inherently* believe they deserve special treatment are generally viewed negatively. *I deserve it because I'm me.* I think it more precisely fits the descriptions. *Greedy* is more general.

Comment: Marvelous, except that the first sentence **does not describe that trait.** Have you read the source? It is Arundhati Roy's _The God of Small Things._ The first sentence has nothing at all to do with greed, entitledness, nor anything at all except the belief of an unlettered person in the munificence of the bus company.

Comment: It fits rather well, in my opinion. It does not exactly match, but more closely than does *greedy.* Maybe you can prevent a tragedy by downvoting my answer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; some of this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44544/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-reynolds-adjective-for-people-who-think-they-should).

Answer (score -1):

What about "[Deserving](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deserving)"?

This happens so she felt she deserved this???

Comment: Note that in the example you give, ‘she felt she deserved’ is the phrase used there, not just ‘deserving’, and OP asked for a single adjective.